# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException in mySQL when inserting / getting data

Tags: java, mysql, junit, connection, database-connection

I am getting this exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

... when calling this method:

```
public class DatabaseDataSetter {

    private static DatabaseConnection database = DatabaseConnection
            .getInstance(); 

    private static Connection conn = database.getConnection();
    private static ArrayList<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Clears complete database.
    public static void dropDatabase() {

        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("DROP DATABASE planning_data"); //--> Execption!
            ps.execute();
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

I am currently testing in JUnit. In the test method, i only call the method `DatabaseDataSetter.dropDatabase()` in a static way. Since that point, no connection is open. After call, an instance of the connection is used, so why it seems to be already closed? The connection-class itself is already tested and delivers connection-instances as expected.

`assertEquals(false,db.getConnection().isClosed());` when a test was made in `DatabaseConnection`, but true, when `DatabaseDataSetter` is called.

Comment: Check for mysql user permission. The user credential you use to connect with mysql has insufficient privileges..i guess.

Comment: User permissions work in "normal" mode. Are there differences when testing?

Comment: How does MySQL know what purpose it is being used for. It works on user's privileges. You must be using an user credential to connect with DB. Check whether "DROP DATABASE" privilege granted to the user or not.

Comment: "all privileges" are given.

Comment: Set autoReconnect property `true`. In hibernate...its like :  `<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database?autoReconnect=true</property>`

Comment: My man! Please mark as answer, so i can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set autoReconnect property true.

In hibernate...its like :

```html
<property> name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database?autoReconnect=tr‌ue</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be your function(`Connection conn = database.getConnection();`) not giving any connection, so that you are getting this connection. If you are using JNDI then might be your connection pool size got exhausted, and not able to give you the connection. If you are using JNDI then please check the JNDI log for this kind of error.

Comment: `assertEquals(false,db.getConnection().isClosed());` when a test was made in `DatabaseConnection`, but true, when `DatabaseDataSetter` is called